# centering unknown width elements inside a known width element

Tags: html, css, layout, width, centering

I didn't find a solution for this problem:

For a nav bar, I have a `ul` with a specific width (530px), and inside it a few `li`s.

I want the `li`s to fill all the 530px width, with equal spaces between them.  I can't hard-code this, as I don't know the width of each `li`.

Comment: Are these list items ("li"s) in a horizontal or vertical direction?

Comment: @Erlik horizontal direction

Comment: Maybe duplicate? [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1695175/how-to-horizontally-center-an-unordered-list-of-unknown-width](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1695175/how-to-horizontally-center-an-unordered-list-of-unknown-width)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend Flexbox - the updated spec is fairly new, and you'll want to use a polyfill or vendor prefixes for broad browser support, but it's the direction this kind of task is going.

Here's a nice tutorial on [creating a simple Flexbox-driven horizontal nav](http://blog.vogtjosh.com/post/4065333647/create-a-horizontal-navigation-with-html5-css3) that will show you the basics.

As [you can see](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox), the browser support isn't yet perfect, but there are various polyfills and techniques available to you to make it rock solid.  And you [don't have to go far](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13934654/is-there-any-polyfill-for-current-css-flexible-box-layout-module-as-per-w3c-cr) to find some more info about those resources.  The key link from that related SO post is Chris Coyier's [Using Flexbox](http://css-tricks.com/using-flexbox/).

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using tables with borders disabled...

Tables will equally separate text into individual cells.

[Here is a nice description about them](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp)