# CSS How to properly use absolutely positioned container with flex childs?

Tags: css, flexbox

Let's get straight to the code with simplified example of my problem.

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container1 {
  border: 2px solid black;
  display: flex;
}

.child {
  padding: 10px;
}

.w100 {
  width: 100px;
}

.f200 {
  flex: 0 0 200px;
}

.green {
  background: #5fd700;
}

.purple {
  background: #9e00ff;
}

.rel {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 80px;
}

.container2 {
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid black;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<h2>Container with position: static</h2>
<h3>width: 100px</h3>
<div class="container1">
  <div class="child green w100">
    child1
  </div>
  <div class="child purple w100">
    child2
  </div>
</div>

<h3>flex-basis: 200px</h3>
<div class="container1">
  <div class="child green f200">
    child1
  </div>
  <div class="child purple f200">
    child2
  </div>
</div>

<h3>width: 100px; flex-basis: 200px</h3>
<div class="container1">
  <div class="child green w100 f200">
    child1
  </div>
  <div class="child purple w100 f200">
    child2
  </div>
</div>

<hr>

<h2>Container with position: absolute</h2>
<h3>width: 100px</h3>
<div class="rel">
  <div class="container2">
    <div class="child green w100">
      child1
    </div>
    <div class="child purple w100">
      child2
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>

<h3>flex-basis: 200px</h3>
<div class="rel">
  <div class="container2">
    <div class="child green f200">
      child1
    </div>
    <div class="child purple f200">
      child2
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>

<h3>width: 100px; flex-basis: 200px</h3>
<div class="rel">
  <div class="container2">
    <div class="child green w100 f200">
      child1
    </div>
    <div class="child purple w100 f200">
      child2
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

I want absolutely positioned container to adjust it's width according to the sizes of it's flex childs. From the screenshot above it's clear that everything works as expected when childs have `width` set explicitly, but when I start to use `flex-basis`, the layout stop to work as expected.

What is the proper way to use flex container with `position:absolute` and childs with `flex-basis`?

Comment: You might want to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41033245/does-position-absolute-conflict-with-flexbox

Comment: you are ok to manipulate the HTML structure or it needs to be the same as you created above?

Comment: @AtulRajput yeah, I'm ok with changing html structure

Comment: @dwjohnston thanks for the link, I've read it. The author of the link's questions faced the problem to stretch absolutely positioned container to the full width of the screen, but my case is different: I want to stretch my container in according to the width of child flex items

Comment: check the bug section of the duplicate *flex-basis fails in Chrome and Firefox when the grandparent container is a shrink-to-fit element. The set-up works fine in Edge.*