# Using position absolute in a child of a flex parent

Tags: html, css, flexbox, position

Im playing around with the flex property and position and I have discovered something.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
}

.mainContainer {
  margin: 10vh auto;
  width: 80vh;
  height: 80vh;
  /* display: flex; */
  justify-content: center;
  /* align-items: center; */
  border: 1px solid red;
  /* position: relative; */
}

.alterContainer {
  position: absolute;
  /* z-index: 1; */
  /* top: 0; */
  align-self: center;
  width: 50vh;
  height: 50vh;
  background-color: #ccc;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.alterContainer1 {
  position: absolute;
  align-self: center;
  /* top: 0; */
  /* z-index: 1; */
  /* top: 0; */
  width: 25vh;
  height: 25vh;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainContainer">
  <div class="alterContainer"></div>
  <div class="alterContainer1"></div>
</div>
```

Thats the code.

I´ve noticed that when positioning a child `position:absolute;` and its parent is `display: flex` what happens is that the child is like the only element in the parent. It goes out-of-flow, it does not "interact" with the other flex-childs.
When positioned absolute, the flex values given to the parent AFFECT this child, on his own.

Anyone has more info about this?

Thanks

Comment: If you do `position: absolute;` on a flex-child element, it will still have flex-alignment until you give it `left`, `right`, `top`, `bottom`.

Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41033245/does-position-absolute-conflict-with-flexbox

https://chenhuijing.com/blog/flexbox-and-absolute-positioning/

Answer (score 1):

in `position : absolute` case the element positions in relative to the nearest positioned ancestor (remember that flex is a display propery that makes the parent a block-level element) , so no there is no way to interact the absolute positioned child with other flex childs ( it can easily overlay them),

if you forced to position an element out of flex container , you can use `postion: relative;` to the child. because relative positioned element is relative to nearest block-level element.